# How to prevent PC on ethernet from losing internet connectivity when other devices are using Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm currently getting internet through a DSL line, goes into the Hub provided by my ISP, which in turn has two ethernet cables, one going to my Desktop, and one going to a wireless router which supplies Wi-Fi to around 8 different devices (not all in use at the same time all the time but can be sometimes).

I'm trying to make my Desktop have priority over any traffic going on in the network as whenever someone uses Wi-Fi for whatever reason, my Desktop connection just gives up and dies (let me clarify, active connections get delayed till they disconnect, new connections fail to establish, until traffic on Wi-Fi stops either by a restart, or by me turning Wi-Fi off).

Now this may sound sad, but I can only get 20 Megabits per second in my area. Getting better internet, or moving to a new home with better internet, are not options I have at this moment.

My goal is to have constant connection, no drop in stability, even if it means constant slow speed as long as the connection remains stable and ping does not fluctuate. How would I go about achieving this?

The Hub provided by the ISP is "BT Smart Hub - Type A" and is the one I'm currently using. Since I got it I tried to use it only as a DSL modem and supply Ethernet to a separate router (EE BrightBox 1 (R)) that does Wi-Fi to the home and Ethernet to my PC, Only to start getting this problem, at first I thought the router I used for Wi-Fi was the problem, so I removed it from the network and tried using the Hub alone, and the problem is still there.

Sadly I cannot use the 2nd router to connect directly do DSL as it's locked to a different ISP (won't allow me to change username when setting up the PPPoE/PPPoA connection), but that has not stopped me from using it as a bridge to the BT Hub.

As suggested in the comments I did some tests with Wi-Fi on, and other devices using it, this is the result:

http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/41405318

And a second test with Wi-Fi turned off and this is the result:

http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/41406663

The test were done while the BT Hub was the only router supplying internet through Wi-Fi and Ethernet (I've removed the EE Brightbox in an attempt to figure out which one was causing the issues)

I am curious to know if a "TP-Link TD-W8961N" has the features that would be required to fix this bufferbloat issue? I had planned to replace the BT Hub with it.

If any information I've supplied is too confusing please lemme know the best way to provide accurate details.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the old title made this question sound too broad, but the body text of the question itself is reasonably specific, and it's a kind of question we usually accept and answer successfully on this site. I've fixed the title on OPs behalf. Please consider reopening.

Comment: When you say your desktop connection "gives up and dies" do you mean you actually lose connectivity? Or do you mean that the connection just gets slow? What do you mean by "drop in stability"? It's not clear whether you're just seeing normal competition/contention when more than one person tries to use a connection or whether something is actually wrong.

Comment: Can you update your Question to include the make and model of your DSL modem (the box your DSL phone line plugs into). It can't be just a hub, and it sounds like it's not just a modem. It sounds like it's a home gateway router with an integrated DSL modem. But I'd like to be able to look at the docs myself, so please post the make (i.e. manufacturer/brand), exact model number, and maybe even the hardware revision, if you can find that information.

Comment: The solution requires reorganizing your network such that everything flows through a router which handles QoS (which I would suggest strongly implies a DD-WRT router). In addition to spiff request for the DSL router details, please provide the WIFI router details, also if you are willing to reconfigure this and/or if you are willing to purchase more hardware.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your PC on Ethernet is losing Internet connectivity (or having it so severely curtailed that it's practically gone), just because other devices are using the Wi-Fi, then it's a bug that needs to be resolved, not some kind of natural ramification of having a busy, fully-loaded network. Using QoS tools to prioritize one kind of traffic over another is a kludgey workaround for this problem. The right fix is to find and resolve the underlying bug (read on).

In most cases, having laggy/slow internet performance while your broadband connection is fully loaded, is a sign of a well-known bug in modems/routers/gateways/APs known as bufferbloat. A common solution to bufferbloat is to load OpenWrt open source router firmware on the device acting as the NAT gateway at the head of your network, and set up an OpenWrt software package called "Cake" (which uses a Smart Queueing algorithm called FQ-CoDel) to combat bufferbloat.

One way to confirm if you have bufferbloat issues is to run http://dslreports.com/speedtest . If you do this, please edit your question to provide a link to your results page. It might be interesting to see the results in a few different cases: From the Ethernet-connected PC in both "good" and "bad" times, and from a Wi-Fi-connected PC/laptop.

Comment: Hello, I've just found this question as I have the same exact problem, PC on Ethernet is losing internet connectivity (long delay times between actions in games, and loading pages abysmally slow), when other users are on Wi-fi, I followed directions to confirm if I do indeed have bufferbloat, and I assume I do, at one point it jumped to 3300+ms, here's the test results
http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/41405318
(Those speeds are what I'm getting out of my contract)

Comment: Upon doing further tests with Wi-Fi disabled it would appear that the bufferbloat is still there, http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/41406663

Comment: @Adrian This is your own question that you asked a week ago, so no wonder you're having the same problem! :-)  Yes, you have terrible bufferbloat. Some of the worst I've seen. What is the brand and exact model of your modem/router? Do you know if OpenWrt supports it?

Comment: I didn't even realize it was my question, I thought it got removed when I was told the title was too broad, and I needed to add details, I just forgot about it.
I'm using "BT Smart Hub - Type A", tried replacing it with a TP-Link TD-W8961N, but the ADSL doesn't work on it for some reason (the port is there, but it can't connect for some reason, even the LED indicator for DSL doesn't light up), so I asked for a replacement, I doubt OpenWrt supports it (BT's router) as it's severely limited in therms of what can be done on it, there's no QoS settings on it, and it looks like I'm stuck with it.